# get primary key or unique error with sql

Tags: php, sql, oracle, triggers

I am working on a ORACLE SQL table which have a primary key on two fields. I would like to retreive primary key error during an insertion with PHP.

I placed code in a try/catch and I don't get any errors.

I don't have a lot of skills with databases, but I know here we use triggers.  Maybe I could catch here the error ?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure to understand what do you mean by layer? I have a table CODING, containing two fields: id and gfy. the primary key is set on these two fields. Its an Oracle database.

Comment: Such as, are you using PDO?  Native extension?  ODBC over COM?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php)

The function that returns the error is oci_error()

to quote from php.net

```
<?php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT does_not_exist FROM dual");
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stid);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    print "\n<pre>\n";
    print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
    printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
    print  "\n</pre>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! If i replace your sql query by "INSERT ...", I should be able to get error I presume! Thank you!